# Could not find a production build in the '/var/www/myapp/.next' directory. Although the build folder is present

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, next.js

I have deployed NextJS app on the ubuntu server. When I try to start the app using **pm2 start npm --name myapp -- start**, I can see that the status of my app is **online**. When I try to open my website in the browser, It shows me **502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)**.
When I ran **pm2 logs** command and checked the logs of pm2, I can see that It is displaying error message inside infinite loop & the error states that:

```
1|myapp  | > sample-app-nodejs@1.0.0 start
1|myapp  | > next start
1|myapp  | ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
1|myapp  | Error: Could not find a production build in the '/var/www/myapp/.next' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production server.
```

So according to the above message, It seems obvious that there is no .next build inside my /var/www/myapp directory. But I have performed **npm run build** inside my app & upon listing the files & folders of my app, I can definately see that there is definitely a .next build inside my app as you can see below.

```
total 1008
  4 drwxrwxrwx  14 root   root     4096 Sep 22 11:56 .
  4 drwxr-xr-x   4 root   root     4096 Sep 22 11:02 ..
  4 -rwxrwxrwx   1 root   root      623 Sep 22 11:01 .env.example
  4 drwxrwxrwx   8 root   root     4096 Sep 22 11:01 .git
  4 -rwxrwxrwx   1 root   root     1609 Sep 22 11:01 .gitignore
  4 drwxrwxrwx   5 root   root     4096 Sep 22 12:02 .next
  4 -rwxrwxrwx   1 root   root      153 Sep 22 11:01 CHANGELOG.md
  4 -rwxrwxrwx   1 root   root     3224 Sep 22 11:01 CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
  4 -rwxrwxrwx   1 root   root     1743 Sep 22 11:01 CONTRIBUTING.md
  4 -rwxrwxrwx   1 root   root     1068 Sep 22 11:01 LICENSE
  4 -rwxrwxrwx   1 root   root     2379 Sep 22 11:01 README.md
  4 -rwxrwxrwx   1 root   root     1112 Sep 22 11:01 app.json
  4 drwxrwxrwx   2 root   root     4096 Sep 22 11:01 assets
  4 drwxrwxrwx   2 root   root     4096 Sep 22 11:01 components
  4 drwxrwxrwx   2 root   root     4096 Sep 22 11:01 constants
  4 drwxrwxrwx   2 root   root     4096 Sep 22 11:01 context
  4 -rwxrwxrwx   1 root   root      558 Sep 22 11:01 jest.config.js
  4 -rwxrwxrwx   1 root   root      150 Sep 22 11:01 jest.setup.ts
  4 drwxrwxrwx   3 root   root     4096 Sep 22 11:01 lib
  4 -rwxrwxrwx   1 root   root      201 Sep 22 11:01 next-env.d.ts
 24 drwxrwxr-x 474 ubuntu ubuntu  20480 Sep 22 11:42 node_modules
880 -rwxrwxrwx   1 root   root   900511 Sep 22 11:42 package-lock.json
  4 -rwxrwxrwx   1 root   root     1623 Sep 22 11:51 package.json
  4 drwxrwxrwx   3 root   root     4096 Sep 22 11:01 pages
  4 drwxrwxrwx   2 root   root     4096 Sep 22 11:01 scripts
  4 drwxrwxrwx   4 root   root     4096 Sep 22 11:01 test
  4 -rwxrwxrwx   1 root   root      909 Sep 22 11:01 tsconfig.json
  4 drwxrwxrwx   2 root   root     4096 Sep 22 11:01 types
```

And here is .next directory content

```
 4 drwxrwxrwx  5 root   root    4096 Sep 22 12:02 .
 4 drwxrwxrwx 14 root   root    4096 Sep 22 11:56 ..
 4 -rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu   749 Sep 22 12:02 build-manifest.json
 4 drwxrwxr-x  4 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Sep 22 11:43 cache
 4 -rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu    20 Sep 22 12:02 package.json
 4 -rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu     2 Sep 22 12:02 react-loadable-manifest.json
 4 drwxrwxr-x  3 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Sep 22 12:02 server
 4 drwxrwxr-x  5 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Sep 22 12:02 static
36 -rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu 35793 Sep 22 12:02 trace
```

Here is my nginx configuraation

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name MY_UBUNTU_IP_ADDRESS_IS_HERE
    
    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types application/javascript application/x-javascript text/css text/javascript;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    
    location /_next/static/ {
        alias /var/www/myapp/.next/static/;
        expires 365d;
        access_log off;
    }
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```